# What is the Proper Way to do this? Calling a Function that's Inside a Pointer-to-a-Pointer-to-a-Pointer?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, 2d

I've got a 3D pointer. I pointed it to a pointer to a "character" object. That object has, as a member of it's class, a pointer to another object type. Let's call that a "die" object type. That die object type has a function that I'd like to use.

I've set it up the way I think it should be, but I get errors. I think I might understand what it's telling me, but not sure if there's an easy workaround to it. If so, I'd love to do that. Would really appreciate some help.

I've tried making it a 3D pointer, but I don't get a different result.

```
int main()
{
    srand (time(0));

    int setter = 1;
    character ***charPtr = new barbarian**(setter); 

    charPtr->ptrAttackDieOne->roll();

    cout << "The roll is" << charPtr->ptrAttackDieOne->getRoll() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

> main.cpp:25:14: error: request for member ‘ptrAttackDieOne’ in ‘* >charPtr’, which is of non-class type ‘character**’
>       charPtr->ptrAttackDieOne->roll();
>                ^
>
> main.cpp:27:39: error: request for member ‘ptrAttackDieOne’ in ‘* >charPtr’, which is of non-class type ‘character**’
>       cout << "The roll is" << charPtr->ptrAttackDieOne->getRoll() << >endl;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To dereference a triple-pointer, you need to deference it twice first:

```cpp
(**charPtr)->ptrAttackDieOne->roll();
```

I also want to point out that this wont' compile:

```cpp
character ***charPtr = new barbarian**(setter);
```

It tries to make a variable of type `barbarian**` and assign it an integer `setter`, which is not allowed. If you want to *create* a 3D pointer, each level has to point to real, allocated memory. `new` can't fill in multiple levels of indirection:

```cpp
    Barbarian*** barbarianFamiliesGroupedBySurname = new Barbarian**[3];
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        barbarianFamiliesGroupedBySurname[i] = new Barbarian*[2];
        for (int j=0; j<2; j++) {
            barbarianFamiliesGroupedBySurname[i][j] = new Barbarian("bob", weapon::axe);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sounds great. I misunderstood what I was doing. Thank you!